# Reemplazo de $ con perfil de maven

Tags: xml, spring, maven

Estoy mirando la manera de conseguir que en mi webapp se pueda hacer una redirección de recursos dependiendo del Sistema Operativo. Quería cambiar la ruta de unos recursos dependiendo de si se usa windows o linux porque en el equipo hay gente que usa las dos cosas y es ineficiente andar comentando y descomentando. Pero me he encontrado un error que no soy capaz de solucionar, estoy haciendo algo muy mal seguramente:

Archivo objetivo del reemplazo (src/main/resources/context/mvc.xml):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="${file.mapping}"></mvc:resources>
```

Perfil de maven:

```
<profile>
    <id>dos</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>dos</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <file.mapping>file:///C:/software/photos/</file.mapping>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Error recurrente:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'file.mapping' in value "${file.mapping}"
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a forzar el perfil añadiendo a la ejecución de maven  `-Pwindows`? al menos para saber si es que no encuentra el perfil o si no encuentra la variable

Comment: Sí, he probado forzándolo y se queja igual. Por eso pienso que he tenido que meter la pata en algo.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Spring usas? ¿Estás usando Spring boot?

Comment: Bueno, oficialmente uso Eclipse. Pero tengo dependencias de Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En las últimas versiones de Spring ellos mismos han creado sus propios perfiles que puedes elegir en tiempo de ejecución (se compilan todos los perfiles a la vez). Esto causaba problemas con Maven y la solución es que las variables de Maven se usan con la notación ${...} dentro del fichero pom.xml, pero con `@...@` en los ficheros.

Creo que si pones

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="@file.mapping@"></mvc:resources>
```

Debería funcionar

Comment: Madre mía. Te amo bro, llevaba siglos luchando con el error. He hecho como 4 preguntas en el Stack Overflow de inglés y solo se peleaban los usuarios entre ellos (no es broma, hasta he borrado la pregunta por el cringe). Lo raro aquí es que  funciona y, al mismo tiempo, tengo más campos utilizando ${} y no saltaba el mismo error. Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: Recupera la pregunta y autorrespóndete en SO